# How to decrypt a large buffer in several fragment ? Bouncy Castle, AES/CTR/NoPadding

Tags: c#, encryption, bouncycastle

I think my question require some basic knowledge i may not have.

I am decrypting a byte array like that:

```
var cipher = CipherUtilities.GetCipher("AES/CTR/NoPadding");
cipher.Init(false, new ParametersWithIV(new KeyParameter(bkey), bIV));
byte[] DecryptedChunk = cipher.ProcessBytes(EncryptedChunk, 0, ChunkSize);
```

I would like to understand how I can cut this buffer in 2 and decrypt the first half and then the second half.

If i just do it like that:

```
var cipher = CipherUtilities.GetCipher("AES/CTR/NoPadding");
cipher.Init(false, new ParametersWithIV(new KeyParameter(bkey), bIV));
byte[] FirstDecryptedChunk = cipher.ProcessBytes(FirstEncryptedChunk, 0, FirstChunkSize);
byte[] SecondDecryptedChunk = cipher.ProcessBytes(SecondEncryptedChunk, 0, SecondChunkSize);
```

Then the first Chunk is ok, but the second one is wrong.

I have spent like 6 hours reading on the internet, I can't find an explanation.
There's something to do with some sort of counter and IV that has to be updated or something?

Comment: If you understand python, this [blog](http://www.laurentluce.com/posts/python-and-cryptography-with-pycrypto/) goes over encryption/decryption in chunks on **Applications** in great detail.

Comment: "*but the second one is wrong*" Is the second chunk complete nonsense data? Is it almost correct, but has strange characters?

Comment: Probably the offset in the buffer or the buffer itself is wrong. Should the offset be 0 in the second buffer? How are the buffers created?

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps there is some confusion here because BC C# version currently provides CTR mode as a block cipher i.e. BufferedBlockCipher, though it ought to be available as a stream cipher (too) i.e. BufferedStreamCipher.

In order to get the full output, you should be calling one of the DoFinal methods (on cipher) after all other processing. The cipher buffers the input a block at a time, and can only output a partial block once it knows you're done.

It would be good practice to call DoFinal even if it were a BufferedStreamCipher, to signal the underlying cipher to clean up and reset for another run.

Answer (score 0):

I can t believe I have spend like 10 hours on that problem !!!!

I just wrote a minimal application, just to isolate the problem, basicaly it is looking like the code i posted in my original thread and IT IS WORKING !!!

I found out in my original code I call .dofinal between each segment, and this is what mess up the next segment !!!!

Pfffiuuu ... 8am, i have spend the whole night on that, i guess i can go to bed ;-)

Comment: Not only that, you were beaten by Peter by 12 minutes, after spending those 8 hours. Glad you got it working though.